# Reference for entropy of a binomial distribution

Tags: entropy

In Wikipedia, the entropy of binomial distribution, Binomial(n,p), is written as
$\frac{1}{2} \ln (2 \pi e n p (1-p)) + O(1/n)$. Can anyone name a reference what is exactly $O(1/n)$, that is, the error terms?

Comment: If the question is 'what does the notation $O(1/n)$ mean' then it's not suitable for this site. You could read about 'big O' notation on the web or ask on math.stackexchange. If instead you want a more precise error term than please clarify this in the question.

Comment: I presume you wish to know the higher order terms in the expansion in powers of  $1/n$, and that is the question I answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Integral Representations and Asymptotic Expansions for Shannon and Renyi Entropies](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82776425.pdf)
 derives the following expansion for the entropy $E(n)$ of the binomial distribution (with $q=1-p$):

[image]